# conditional expectation and sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, P)$ be some probability measure and $(X_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ a family of independent random variables such that all $X_i$ have expected value $m$ and Variance $\sigma^2$. Let T be a random variable which is independent of all $X_i$ and consider the random variable $S_T:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^T X_i$.

Show that $\mathbb{E}[S_T \vert T]=m\cdot T$ and $\mathbb{E}[S_T]=m\mathbb{E}[T]$.

I tried to prove these equations but I was not successful. Do you have a hint for me?

Suppose, $A\in\sigma(T)$, Then the first equation holds if and only if $\int_A S_T = m\int_A T$. We know that by definition : $\int_A S_T= \sum\limits_{i=1}^T \int_A X_i = \sum\limits_{i=1}^T \mathbb{E}[X 1_A]$. But how can I prove the above equations.

Hope you can help me.

BEst regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(S_T|T=k) = E(S_k|T=k) = E(S_k) = mk$ where the last equation follows by independence. Now taking expectation on both sides yields $E(S_T) = mE(T)$.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $T=t$ you have that $$E[S_T|T=t]=E[S_t]=m\cdot t$$ Thus $$E[S_T|T]=E[E[S_T|T]]=E[mT|T]=mE[T|T]=m\cdot T$$

---

Similarly $$E[S_T]=\sum_{t}E[S_T|T=t]P(T=t)=\sum_{t}mtP(T=t)=mE[T]$$